# Help needed declaring code-behind controls

Tags: c#, asp.net

OK - back for help sooner than expected.

I've got a c# web project and am having trouble with my controls. I'm trying to do something pretty simple - just changing a couple of labels on a page.

When I try and build the project it errors with a NullReferenceException error, which I think may be down to my not having declared the controls properly.

I'm pretty new to c#, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code I am using is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("Albums.txt"));
         Album[] Albums = new Album[allLines.Length];
         for (int i = 0; i < allLines.Length; i++)
         {
           string[] lineSplit = allLines[i].Split(',');
           Albums[i] = new Album();
           Albums[i].ID = Convert.ToInt32(lineSplit[0]);
           Albums[i].title = lineSplit[1];
           Albums[i].keyName = lineSplit[2];
       }

        this.albumID.Text = Convert.ToString(Albums[0].ID);
        this.albumTitle.Text = "Hello World";
        this.albumKeyName.Text = Albums[0].keyName;           
   }
```

and the albumID, albumTitle and albumKeyName controls are defined in the default.designer.cs page created by VS.

Cheers,

Ben

PS - aspx markup:

```
<body>
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="albumID" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="albumTitle" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="albumKeyName" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</form>
```

To try and pinpoint the problem I've removed a load of the code to just leave the following:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.albumTitle.Text = "Hello World";          
   }
}
```

It's erroring on the "Hello World" line with a NullReferenceException - the details below the error say: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Sorry about the array - looks like it was a red herring.

Comment: Can we see your aspx markup as well?  Which line is the error thrown on?

Comment: Here's the aspx markup:

<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="albumID" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="albumTitle" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="albumKeyName" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </form>
</body>

Comment: Balls - that didn't format too well! Will add it as an edit to the main question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set a breakpoint and tried stepping through it?

My suggestion would be to first make sure that the `allLines` array is not null before accessing the `Length` property on it.

Another possible cause would be that allLines length was 0, so no Albums were ever created. (Which means `Albums[0].ID` would be a NullReferenceException).

Comment: I tried testing by commenting out the albumID and albumKeyName lines, so it wasn't "touching" the array, but still got the same error.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on your declartion of allLines and step through the method, can you tell us on what line the error is being thrown? If it's not making it that far down the method, then the next possible cause is allLines is null and you're trying to access the Length property of it.

Comment: Looking at it, I think the array is a red herring.

I've edited it to remove all but the line that sets albumTitle to "hello world" and still get the same error, on that line.

Answer (score 0):

This looks ok without seeing your markup, as long as the three controls do exist in the markup.

There are a number of places that could be null - `Albums[0]`, `lineSplit` and `allLines` are all candidates for nulls.

Comment: I could be mistaken, but lineSplit would throw an IndexOutOfRangeException, wouldn't it? Not a NullReferenceException?

Answer (score 0):

What does your `<%@ Page %>` directive look like?  Are you by any chance using `CodeBehind` instead of `CodeFile`?

Answer (score 0):

Sorted now - still don't know what the error was, but deleted the files and recreated them and it all worked fine.

Chalk it up to a frustrating mystery. :-(